# Early return from a loop in a task expression (CE)

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I'd like to implement a retry utility for TPL-`Task`s in F#, for retrying things like  `HttpClient.GetAsync(...)`.

Specification: it will retry a given task-starting function up to *n* times by swallowing any exceptions that might be thrown. But for the last iteration, it should propagate any exceptions to the caller rather than swallowing it (with a meaningful stack trace).

In C#, it'd be as simple as

```c#
  public static async Task<T> RetryTask<T>(int n, D<T> d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
      try {
        return await d.Invoke();
      } catch (Exception) { }
    }
    return await d.Invoke();
  }
```

https://sharplab.io/#gist:e6b5416c410e879e8ddbd067cdd9a9c2

But my best attempt in F# looks as cluttered as

```f#
let retryTask n (f: unit -> 'T Task): 'T Task = task {
  match!
    task {
      let mutable found = false
      let mutable value = Unchecked.defaultof<'T>
      let mutable i = 0
      while i < n - 1 && not found do
        if 0 < i then
          do! Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100. * float i))
        i <- i + 1
        try
          let! ret = f()
          found <- true
          value <- ret
        with _ -> ()
      return if found then Some value else None
    }
  with | Some ret -> return ret
       | None -> return! f()
}
```

https://sharplab.io/#gist:65c3fdadacc470127b9cfa8bb2e4cb0e

THREE `mutable` variables! Am I missing anything?

Comment: Try a recursive solution. Much cleaner.

Comment: F# suggestion for early returns from loops https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/1101. It would look like [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AbEAzAzmgFxAEsMAfDGAgAlgKgE8BBXBgOzAB4ByAFQD5qACjYhqxNgTTUAJmIAiPAQEpqY3gENcAayWCAvAFgAUNTPUCW7dQDeJ8w+rZo46vuoAGCxGps4AJlkIe0dQ+gYQ0KjqSgIAQlo3WQA6AEk2ADcIbRghZUjox2BYDWsoAuiAd2ICAAtqAH1qOEE8iocYDFwYdqjYhKgkmTTM7Nz800LzcsmzAF8gA=) if this to be implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
let retry nTimes makeTask =

    let rec loop nTimes =
        task {
            try return! makeTask ()
            with _ when nTimes > 0 ->
                do! Async.Sleep 1000
                return! loop (nTimes - 1)
        }

    loop nTimes
```

Comment: Oh so you think [growing a stack frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/task-expressions#limitations-of-tasks-regarding-tailcalls) won't be a problem here... That's certainly correct, the retry limit will likely be a single digit number. Also it's refreshing to see `with` used with a guard clause on something other than examining an exception property. Hmm, if I come up with a problem that actually requires an early return from a loop in a task, I'll post again...

Comment: Good point. I agree that this should only be used to loop a small number of times.

Comment: Tail recursion should solve the growing stack frame issue.

Comment: @Foole, `task`s doesn't support tail call optimization, while `async`s do support it